# Bootstrap row elements not taking whole width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a webpage off of this bootstrap [model](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/fluid.html). The problem I am facing, and what I cannot figure out, is why the two companies inside the `span10` class do not take up the entire row?

The easiest way to understand this would be to first look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GgSxJ/1/). Then, do an `inspect element` on the company row. Notice that the `span10 div` is taking up the correct width (its going to the end of the page). However, the two `span5` divs inside of that should be taking up the entire width inside the `span10`. At least, according to my understanding of the bootstrap scaffolding, they should be. (I may be mistaken). In any case, they are not taking up the whole width as I believe they should.

The CSS in the fiddle is copied straight from an uneditted bootstrap file. So the css should not be the problem (with version 3 coming out, I was having trouble pulling from the bootstrap server).

Also, the problem is not (I dont think) having a row within a row, because if you look at the bootstrap example page I provided, that is what they are doing and it is working for them :).

If it is unclear what I am asking, please ask questions and I will reply promptly!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap uses a 12-column grid layout, so use `.span6` if you want two columns to take the whole width of the row. Every new row inside a column will be treated as a full 12-column grid.

Comment: You are exactly right. Thanks for the quick response. I didn't even notice the sub rows in the bootstrap example add up to 12 (facepalm!).